# How can I determine if two values are adjacent in a string?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

(In Python 3)

```
def melting_temperature(dna_sequence, formula):
if formula == 'c':
    return melting_temperature_count(dna_sequence)
else:
    modern = melting_temperature_count(dna_sequence)
    for i in len(range(dna_sequence)):
        if dna_sequence[i] == 'a' and dna_sequence[i+1] == 't':
            modern += modern * 0.01
    return modern
```

My If statements calculates the melting temperature of the dna_sequence. 
In my Else statement it re runs melting_temperature_count (previously defined function) and uses that calculated number and then adds 1% if 'A' and 'T' are adjacent in the dna_sequence. I don't know how to compare indices but I came up with this however it is returning an error
    builtins.TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
Can someone please tell me how I can see if two things are adjacent? I hope I explained this well enough.

Comment: `len(range(dna_sequence))` should be `range(len(dna_sequence))`.

Comment: Do you add 1% for every instance in which an A is adjacent to T?

Comment: Yeah. For example, if it was 'ghat' it would be + 1% and if it was 'atatgy' it would be +1 % three times (at, ta, at)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
def ATadjacentCount(s):
    return len([x for x,y in zip(s,s[1:]) if set((x,y)) == set(('A','T'))])
```

For example:

```
>>> ATadjacentCount("ATGTAGTAG")
3
```

To get a feel for how it works consider:

```
ATGTAGTAG
TGTAGTAG
*  *  *
```

You can of course change to lower case if you want. Note that adding 1% to a quantity is equivalent to multiplying it by 1.01. If k is the count of adjacent AT pairs then you could multiply by 1.01 ** k -- you don't have to do the adjustments in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string into a list and iterate through the list comparing the adjacent values, something like

```
temp = "string" 
lis = list(temp)
for i in range(0, len(lis)-1):
    if lis[i] == 'n' and lis[i+1] == 'i' or lis[i] == 'n' and lis[i-1] == 'i':
            print "Adjacent"
```